# O que significa -> em PHP?

Tags: php

Estou estudando um pouco php para usar em um trabalho e me deparei com um trecho de código na internet em que é utilizado "->" no código e eu não consegui encontrar nenhuma página que tratasse deste elemento do código.

```
return $stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

(`->`) esse operador é conhecido informamente como seta, o [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php) chama ele de `T_OBJECT_OPERATOR` serve para acessar propriedades ou métodos de um objeto, para membros estáticos(aqueles que pertencem/compartilhados a classe) utiliza-se o `::` [Paamayim Nekudotayim](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php#language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim).

Outras linguagens como java e C# utilizam ponto no lugar(`.`) no lugar de (`->`).

Comment: Em C e C#, o `->` tem um comportamento igual ao do `.`, mas somente quando aplicado à um ponteiro.

Answer (score 12):

Em [objetos e classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php), esse `->` ([`T_OBJECT_OPERATOR`](http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php)) é a maneira de aceder a uma propriedade ou método.

Por exemplo:

```
$obj = new StdClass;

$obj->foo = "bar";
echo $obj->foo; // vai dar "bar"
```

Portanto podes usar como *setter*

```
$obj->foo = "bar";
```

e como *getter* se não atribuires nenhum valor com `=`.

Answer (score 5):

Apesar de que foi perguntado apenas do operador de seta, acho que quem tem a dúvida sobre esse operador, terá também no mínimo sobre esses outros dois operadores, como eu tive no começo:

#### operador seta

`->`  é usado para acessar método ou propriedade de instância de classe [ou para acessar método ou propriedade de um objeto].

```
$obj = new Cliente();
$obj->nome = 'Fred';
$obj->getNome();
```

---

#### operador de resolução de escopo

`::` Já que mencionamos o operador seta, é bom saber que há o operador
que é usado quando você deseja chamar um método estático, acessar uma variável estática, constantes, e métodos sobrecarregados.
Ele é chamado de Operador de Resolução de Escopo, ou também é chamado de Paamayim Nekudotayim, ou em termos mais simples, dois pontos duplo.

exemplo:

```
<?php
class MinhaClasse {
  const VALOR_CONST = 'Um valor constante';
}
echo MinhaClasse::VALOR_CONST;
?>
```

---

#### operador de seta dupla

Lembrando que há também o operador de seta dupla:

`=>` é usado para atribuir valores para chaves de matrizes [arrays]

```
$meuArray = array(
  0 => 'Big',
  1 => 'Small',
  2 => 'Up',
  3 => 'Down'
);
```

outro exemplo:

```
$ages = array("Peter"=>32, "Quagmire"=>30, "Joe"=>34, 1=>2);
```

---

Em Java, Javascript, .NET não há a diferença entre `->`, `=>` e `::`
Nessas linguagens você usa o operador `.` e para arrays apenas `[` e `]`