# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$erro' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\HITSS\cadastrar.php on line 26

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estou com o erro do título no meu código, será que alguém pode me dar uma luz?

```
<?php $erro = array('1');

include("conexao.php");


    if(isset($_POST['Entrar'])) {

        //1 - REGISTRO DOS DADOS

        if(!isset($_SESSION))
            session_start();

        foreach ($_POST as $chave=>$valor) {
            $_SESSION[$chave] = $mysqli -> real_escape_string($valor);

        //2 - VALIDAÇÃO DOS DADOS


        if(strlen($_SESSION['login']) == 0)
            $erro[] = "Preencha a senha.";

        if(strlen($_SESSION['nome']) == 0)
            $erro[] = "Preencha o nome.";

        if((substr_count($_SESSION['email'], '@') != 1 || substr_count($_SESSION['email'], '.') < 1 || substr_count($_SESSION['email'], '.') > 2)
            $erro[] = "Preencha o e-mail corretamente.";

        if(strlen($_SESSION['nivel'] == 0)
            $erro[] = "Preencha o nivel.";

        if(strlen($_SESSION['cargo']) == 0)
            $erro[] = "Preencha o cargo.";

        if(strlen($_SESSION['nascimento']) == 0)
            $erro[] = "Preencha a data de nascimento.";

        if(strlen($_SESSION['admissao']) == 0)
            $erro[] = "Preencha a data de admissão.";

        if(strlen($_SESSION['senha']) < 8 || strlen($_SESSION['senha']) > 16)
            $erro[] = "Preencha a senha.";

        if(strcmp($_SESSION['senha'], $_SESSION['conf_senha']) != 0
            $erro[] = "Opa, as senhas estão diferentes.";


        //3 - INSERÇÃO NO BANCO

        if(cont($erro) == 0) {


            $sql_code = "INSERT INTO users (
                login, 
                nome, 
                email, 
                nivel, 
                cargo, 
                dat_nasc, 
                dat_adm, 
                foto)
                VALUES(
                '$_SESSION[login]',
                '$_SESSION[nome]',
                '$_SESSION[email]',
                '$_SESSION[nivel]',
                '$_SESSION[cargo]',
                '$_SESSION[nascimento]',
                '$_SESSION[adimissao]',
                '$_SESSION[foto]',
                '$_SESSION[senha]'
                )";
            $confirma = $mysqli- >query($sql_code) or die($mysqli- >error);

            if($confirma) {
                unset($_SESSION[login],
                $_SESSION[nome],
                $_SESSION[email],
                $_SESSION[nivel],
                $_SESSION[cargo],
                $_SESSION[nascimento],
                $_SESSION[adimissao],
                $_SESSION[foto],
                $_SESSION[senha]);

                echo "<scrip> location.href='user_cadastro.php';</script>"
            }
            else {
                $erro[] = $confirma;
            }


        }
        else {
            foreach ($erro as $valor) echo "div class='erro'>"; echo "</div>"; "$valor <br>";
        }

    }


?>
```

Comment: Faltou `;` nessa linha? `echo "<scrip> location.href='user_cadastro.php';</script>"` ?

Answer (score 3):

Você esqueceu de fechar alguns parêntesis. Veja as linhas abaixo:

Linha 26:

```
if((substr_count($_SESSION['email'], '@') != 1 || substr_count($_SESSION['email'], '.') < 1 || substr_count($_SESSION['email'], '.') > 2))
    $erro[] = "Preencha o e-mail corretamente.";
```

Linha 29:

```
if(strlen($_SESSION['nivel'] == 0))
    $erro[] = "Preencha o nivel.";
```

Linha 44:

```
if(strcmp($_SESSION['senha'], $_SESSION['conf_senha']) != 0)
     $erro[] = "Opa, as senhas estão diferentes.";
```

Já na linha 49, a função `cont` não existe. Provavelmente, você quer usar a função `count`, que serve para contar os itens de um `array`.

```
 if(count($erro) == 0) {
```

Linha 73, não use espaços no [Object Separator](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90846/o-que-significa-em-php)

```
  $confirma = $mysqli->query($sql_code) or die($mysqli->error);
```

Na linha 86, você não usou `;` no final da sentença:

```
 echo "<scrip> location.href='user_cadastro.php';</script>";
```

E, por fim, você não fechou o `if` que abriu na linha `6`.

Com toda sinceridade, aconselho que você estude a melhor a sintaxe da linguagem, para não ficar perdido.

**Dica**: Use um editor de texto ou IDE que faça um lint do seu código, para saber se ele tem erro de sintaxe.

Para descobrir o erro, eu usei o site [PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/)

Comment: Além de faltar um `;` na linha 85 e na linha 94 possuir um `foreach` mal formatado, com três instruções sem estar limitada por chaves e uma *string* perdida, provavelmente porque faltou um `echo` (e um elemento `<div>` sem o `<` do início, que não é problema no PHP), e a ordem dos valores não faz muito sentido - colocar o texto de erro fora do elemento.