# Qual a diferença entre -> e [''] no PHP?

Tags: php, array, classes, sintaxe

Eu estava analisando uns códigos na web e deparei dois métodos para chamar um objeto de uma *string*, por exemplo:

#### Código 1:

```
$retorno->nome;
```

Ele retornava o valor do nome.

#### Código 2:

```
$retorno['nome'];
```

e ele também trazia o nome.

Gostaria de entender qual a diferença entre os dois, principalmente como cada um deles funciona.

Comment: Relacionado a [O que significa -> em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90846/o-que-significa-em-php)

Comment: Não consegui replicar a alegação da pergunta https://ideone.com/YeaDYT

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos, que terá logo depois da aceitação).

Answer (score 1):

Internamente não tem muita. Grosso modo, o primeiro acaba virando o segundo porque PHP, até as últimas versões que eu vi, não tem estruturas de dados reais, tudo acaba virando [*array* associativo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104701/101). O `nome` acaba virando `['nome']`.

O processo pode ser visto com mais detalhes em [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40682/101). Não é igual ao JavaScript, mas é muito parecido.

E pode ver mais sobre [nomenclatura de algumas estruturas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/429851/101).

A primeira forma é usada com sintaxe de classe, então parece mais como orientação a objeto e de fato quando usa uma classe é forma a ser usada.

Eu não sei como usou o código, mas em condições normais as sintaxes não são intercambiáveis e não produzem o mesmo resultado.

```
class teste {
    public $nome = "João";
}
$retorno = array( 'nome' => 'João');
echo $retorno->nome;
echo "---\n";
echo $retorno['nome'];
echo "\n---\n";
$retorno = new teste();
echo $retorno->nome;
//echo $retorno['nome'];
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/pSFWu1). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/qhzqyahgvo-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/MemberXElement.php).

Se usar um *array* e tentar pegar com `->` virá nada. Se criar uma classe e usar o `['']` dará erro.

Portanto a primeira indica um membro de uma estrutura de dados (classe) e ou outro indica um elemento de um *array*.

Comment: Entendi, então se eu quiser utilizar o [''] terei que criar um array, isso?

Comment: De maneira geral é isso.